# Calculus 2: Find Integral of Trig Integrand with cosine multiplied by sine

Tags: calculus

I'm reviewing the math problem below with a solution provided by the teacher.  I think there's an error but wanted to verify ...

I think the expression should get multiplied by -5 instead of -1/5 ... am I offbase here?

[image]

Comment: $-\frac{1}{5\sin{5x}}du=dx$ so this looks correct.

Comment: sorry, don't quite understand what is that referring to?

Comment: "I think the expression should get multiplied by -5 instead of -1/5 ... am I offbase here?" Wasn't that your question?